# Removing dual boot and installing ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I had the dual boot: Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.2.

Then I tried to install ubuntu 12.04.2 on the entire hard disk. The trouble is that as the installation begin, it isn't going beyond copying the files. That is, it stuck at the point where it ask for naming the system.

I then downloaded ubuntu 12.04.3, and tried to install from it. But again, it isn't going beyond this point.

Please help me out. It has been a week trying whatever I could and now I'm too tired...!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the installer continues to copy the files in the background while you fill in the details and choose timezone and such. So lack of visible action may not mean that it isn't happening.

How long do you wait before giving up?

Comment: I have waited for 3 to 5 hours. Once I let it go for the entire night, that was I believe about 12 hours waiting time. Eventually then I shut down or restart the system. 

And then I whenever I tried to re-install again, installation menu suggests as if Ubuntu got installed, though no boot option was appeared on the start up. I've done this re-installation at least ten times.

Comment: I think I should install windows 7 again. That is, go back to dual boot system. And then resize the window partition to as less as possible as I would never user it. This will make at least my 20 GB out of 100 to be useless...phew...